# Xero Invoice - API Character limit in Apex Salesforce

Tags: http, url, salesforce, apex, xero-api

I'm new to salesforce and i'm trying to Integrate Xero Invoice.

While calling the API **GET https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Invoices/** i've got one question in my mind that what will be the character limit of URL/API for making the HTTP request?
for example, i want to specific Invoices which matches ContactIds

```
GET https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Invoices/?IDs=220ddca8-3144-4085-9a88-2d72c5133734,88192a99-cbc5-4a66-bf1a-2f9fea2d36d0
```

Answer (score 0):

It's 2048 characters, which will be about 50 IDs, depending on your other query parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.